# No resources (img, js, css) loaded when .htaccess redirects to .php file

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I want to redirect pages without extension to a php file.
E.g.
https://example.com/starrysky/ => https://example.com/starrysky.php
I already have a working redirect from HTML to PHP:
https://example.com/starrysky.html redirects correctly https://example.com/starrysky.php .

When I redirect *.html* to *.php* in *.htaccess* it works flawlessly: it redirects *.html* to *.php*, so I thought, replacing the final `.html$` by `/$` (ending with a slash) would redirect to php but that did not work.

This does work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php
```

But this does not:

```
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php
```

Prepending a backslash to the slash + dollar in the last line won't help.
And uncommenting the RewriteCond line above won't help me either.

I'd like that https://example.com/starrysky/ redirects to https://example.com/starrysky.php.

It does, but the css, js and images are not loaded, despite being relative to the same document root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)